# Tascam DR-40 and ntg2 mic noise hissss

Tags: tascam, sound-design, rode

I hav been using a rode ntg2 and a tascam could to not afford a zoom and seemed just the same. I am recording with it but when I go to stero I hear a hissing sound in the left channel when I turn the gain up as well as mono.

And I am a student in college majoring in film production focus on sound design any tips and tricks as well will be more then welcomely taken. I am beginning to learn a lot I learned a lot from my freshman year. I am loving post production sound design. I am using my kit to build a sound library.

So ya any tips more then welcome.

Comment: The hiss is the recorder's preamplifier's self-noise? NTG-2 has some self-noise as well, but mostly it's the pocket recorders that have subpar signal-to-noise ratio/performance.

Comment: I agree with @Internet Human. I have a DR-40 too. Its built-in mics are good, but I too have experienced noise and hiss issues when I used  an external mic.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned above the problem is a result of the high recorders selfnoise. You would have the same problem with the zoom, at least the tascam has a decent line level.

Have you tried switching of the phantom power on your device and running your røde on battery power? This should help a lot!

Otherwise if you like post production you can rehearse noise reduction until you have gathered enough money to buy a mixer to put in front of you recorder :-)

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've found is that the Rode do NOT like 24v phantom... using them results in higher noise and generally reduced performance. Set the phantom power to 48v. This will result in your battery draining a lot faster, but will probably reduce the hiss. Alternately use the battery in the Mic as FAO suggested. I've used the NT's with a few things and found it to be a problem (even with my trusty FP33 as a front end). In all fairness, it's also an issue with my AKG C451's as well.